# PHP simplehtmldom find text in blank table structure

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm having difficulty finding the **DYNAMIC-TEXT** value in a sea of HTML tables.

I have tried `$html->find("th[plaintext*=Type")` and from here, I wanted to access the sibling, but return nothing. Here's the table structure

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%">
        <col>
    </colgroup>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <th width="30%">Type</th>
            <td>DYNAMIC-TEXT</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect the output to be the text of *DYNAMIC-TEXT* but the action output is nothing

Thanks

Comment: Sooo, where are the `th` elements?

Comment: my idea was getting ```<th width="30%">Type</th>``` and then access its sibling, which is ```<td>DYNAMIC-TEXT</td>``` but not success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$html->find("th[plaintext*=Type")` you want to use an [attribute selector](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#frag_find_attr) `*=` but there is no attribute `plaintext`.

But there is an attribute width with the value 30%. You might use a pattern `^[0-9]+%$` to check for 1+ digits followed by a percentage sign.

If you find a result, you could get the [next_sibling](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#frag_traverse_traverse) and get the [plaintext](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#frag_access_special) from it.

For example:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach ($html->find("th[width*=^[0-9]+%$]") as $value) {
    echo $value->next_sibling()->plaintext;
}
```

Result:

```
DYNAMIC-TEXT
```